# autoscroll panel to bottom

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have a panel in my winforms and in it i load some usercontrols .

i would like to autoscroll to the bottom of the panel( as my panel fills ) everytime a new usercontrol is added . How can i do so ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do that by setting the `VerticalScroll` of the Panel but I think it would be better to use `ScrollControlIntoView` instead.

```
private void panel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(e.Control);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This seems to work... one thing I found weird though, is While the other controls in the panel move up accordingly, TableLayoutPanels that are children to the scrolling panel do NOT move up. You have to manually move those yourself, programmatically after scrolling. Odd.

Answer (score 22):

You could use [ScrollControlIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview.aspx) and pass the control you last added.

An alternate solution would be:

```
panel.VerticalScroll.Value = panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum
```

Comment: Anyone trying this solution who has the problem of the scrollbars not updating, you need to call PerformLayout() after setting Value. Problem and solution confirmed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565653/scrollbar-does-not-update-on-changing-the-scroll-value

Comment: Notice, If you adding usercontrolls dynamicly you have to also update the value of panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found that continuously adding controls to the panel at vertical increments would be affected negatively whenever a user had scrolled the panel up or down. I used the tip from Homam above, and found the following to work well:

```
panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;

// Creating and adding a TextBox, tb, to the panel

panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(tb);
```

So first, I scroll to the top in order to use absolute vertical positions for my text boxes, then I place the Text Box, and finally, I make sure that the newly created text box comes into view.