# Scrollbar does not update on changing the scroll value

Tags: .net, winforms, scrollbar

When setting `VerticalScroll.Value` in a `Panel` with `AutoScroll` set to `true`, the scroll position changes accordingly but the position of the thumb does not. Do I need to update the scrollbar somehow (`Invalidate(true)` on the panel does not work)? Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try calling [`.PerformLayout();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8aw0sd8.aspx#Y342)

Comment: Yep, can confirm, this works flawlessly for me on 3 different controls. Thanks.

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the `.PerformLayout()` tip!

It wasn't enough in my case, I am setting the VerticalScroll.Value within the form `Form.Shown` event handler, and for some reason I had to add a `DoEvents` instruction beforehand for the scrolling to work.

Here's my `Shown` event handler:

```
Private Sub MyForm_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

    ScrollPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = ScrollPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum
    ScrollPanel.PerformLayout()
End Sub
```

ScrollPanel control is of type `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`.

Without the `Application.DoEvents()` line, the vertical scrolling value setting was completely ignored.

I thought it might came in handy for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue when trying to autoscroll a panel containing a picture box.

I found another method to make it work. Increment the scroll value twice:

```
ScrollPanel.VerticalScroll.Value += AmountToScroll

ScrollPanel.VerticalScroll.Value += AmountToScroll
```

Incrementing the value the first time causes the picture box to scroll within the panel, but the .Value doesn't change and the thumb doesn't move.

Incrementing the value the second time causes the VerticalScroll.Value to be incremented, moving the thumb, but the picture box is not scrolled again.

Seems like a bug to me. Surely both the scrolling of the picture box and the incrementing of the .Value and movement of the thumb should happen after the first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something nearly identical where I have a PictureBox (showing a graph) inside a panel with scroll bars, and I want to zoom in or out keeping the mouse-pointer position "apparently" stationary.  Re-positioning the PictureBox inside the panel to do this throws off synchronization with the scroll bars, and thereafter, scrolling with the scroll bars will not show the full area of the PictureBox.  The solution is to accomplish the move by assigning a computed value to the panel.HorizontalScroll.Value and/or panel.VerticalScroll.Value properties.  But that alone isn't enough:  one of these two solutions is required to make the application behave as designed:

1. KMan's solution above:

   ```
   panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = computed_value
   panel.PerformLayout()
   ```
2. Or JJMcLellan's solution above:  in my case, assigning the computed value twice, e.g.:

   ```
   panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = computed_value
   panel.HorizontalScroll.Value = computed_value
   ```

Either one of these appears to have the same end results.  Since #2 above makes it look like a bug, and #1 seems (hopefully) to be by design by Microsoft (?), I ended up using #1 in my application.  I just wanted to confirm both these work in a VB.NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get it to work on a Form.  I tried the PerformLayout(), I tried Application.DoEvents(), I tried assigning the VerticalScroll.Value twice, none of it worked.  The only thing I got to work was to change a property of VerticalScroll to a different value, and then change it back:

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArg e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
    if (this.Visible)
    {
        this.VerticalScroll.Maximum++;
        this.VerticalScroll.Maximum--;
    }
}
```

Note that it works just as well to change VerticalScroll.Value, but you have to actually modify its value, and making sure the change is in the range of Minimum to Maximum is a lot more complex than just increasing Maximum temporarily.

Comment: The OnVisibleChanged issue probably means your problem is different than what the questioner posted.

Comment: I think you're right... I think the difference is mine was setting the scrollbar properties before opening the form, whereas this question is about positioning an already visible scrollbar.  I think it's worth leaving this answer under the question, even if the scenario is slightly different.