# Mousewheel scroll inconsistent with two tablelayoutpanels

Tags: vb.net, scroll, mousewheel, tablelayoutpanel

I have two tablelayoutpanels side by side.
The scroll events of both panels are linked so the user scrolls one and the other scrolls too.  This works fine:

```
Private Sub Layout_SidePanel_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Layout_SidePanel.Scroll

    If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then
        'make the other panel scroll too
        Layout_Main.VerticalScroll.Value = Layout_SidePanel.VerticalScroll.Value

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Layout_Main_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Layout_Main.Scroll

    If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then
        'make the other panel scroll too
        Layout_SidePanel.VerticalScroll.Value = Layout_Main.VerticalScroll.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

However, when the user uses the mousewheel to scroll it doesn't work at all well.  One side will scroll and not the other.  Or one will scroll a bit more than the other.  I've checked the vertical scroll values of the two panels and can see they don't match up.  I need to either get the scrolling to work consistently or disable the mousewheel scrolling.
This is my code for handing the mousewheel events:

```
     Private Sub Layout_Main_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Layout_Main.MouseWheel

    Layout_SidePanel.VerticalScroll.Value = Layout_Main.VerticalScroll.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Layout_Sidepanel_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Layout_SidePanel.MouseWheel

    Layout_Main.VerticalScroll.Value = Layout_SidePanel.VerticalScroll.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5565804/3953342

I need to include .PerformLayout

```
Layout_SidePanel.VerticalScroll.Value = Layout_Calendar.VerticalScroll.Value
Layout_SidePanel.PerformLayout()
```