# How do I first capture and then set scrollbar's position?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a program that stores data. A form creates a panel with read only text boxes for each result found in my database query.  The Form has autoscroll set to True. When the user clicks on a specific record's update button another form opens to handle the update. The first form then clears all controls and redraws them to reflect the update. My Problem: The redrawn form's scrollbar is always at the top. I want the scrollbar to scroll back to its position before the update. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read and set `Form.HorizontalScroll.Value` and `Form.VerticalScroll.Value`.
You can also check `Form.HorizontalScroll.Visible`, but the `.value` is 0 if it is not visible, so this should be irrelevant.

Don't go over the maximum when recalling, e.g.
`frm.HorizontalScroll.Value = Math.Min(SavedValueH, frm.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)`

However, Winforms has some problems when the scrollvalue is set through code, [see answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565653/scrollbar-does-not-update-on-changing-the-scroll-value).