# How to scroll a panel to the bottom in c#?

Tags: c#, scroll, panel

I have a panel `MessagesPanel` that contains messages which are retrieved from a database. I go over the messages using a `foreach` loop. In the loop, I call a function `AddMessageToPanel` which dynamically adds a `GroupBox` to the panel, with the message information and content. The messages are retrieved oldest to newest, top to down (Like in WhatsApp). The panel is set to `AutoScroll=true`, and I want it to scroll to the very bottom to the newest message.
I tried those solutions:

1. [autoscroll panel to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500561/autoscroll-panel-to-bottom)
2. [How to Programmatically Scroll a Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752970/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-panel)
3. [How to scroll a panel manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262534/how-to-scroll-a-panel-manually)

None of them worked for me. The panel just looks the same, with the scroll bar at the top.

In particular, I have tried the following codes:

```
private void MessagePanel_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessagesPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(e.Control);
}
```

and I subscribe to it with the event `ControlAdded`.

And also:

```
MessagesPanel.VerticalScroll.Value = MessagesPanel.VerticalScroll.Maximum
```

With and without `MessagesPanel.SuspendLayout()`;

Here is my function:

```
private void AddMessageToPanel(string sender, string datetime, string content)
{
    GroupBox groupBox = new GroupBox();
    groupBox.Location = new Point(0, 120 * MessagesPanel.Controls.Count);
    groupBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
    groupBox.Size = new Size(500, 100);
    groupBox.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", sender, datetime);

    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Enabled = false;
    textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
    textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    textBox.Multiline = true;
    textBox.Size = new Size(495, 95);
    textBox.Location = new Point(0, 20);
    textBox.Text = content;

    groupBox.Controls.Add(textBox);
    MessagesPanel.Controls.Add(groupBox);
}
```

I want the `MessagesPanel` to scroll all the way down. How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Try to call `ScrollControlIntoView` passing it instance of item you added last. Preferably not earlier than `Form.Shown` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alternative to Beldi's solution, you can call

```
MessagesPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, MessagesPanel.DisplayRectangle.Height);
```

after all the controls have been added to the panel.

Comment: As stated by Sinatr above, you probably run this before the Form.Shown Event has occured. You need to wait for that event before applying the AutoScrollPosition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ScrollControlIntoView() method. Like this:

```
  groupBox.Controls.Add(textBox);
  MessagesPanel.Controls.Add(groupBox);
  MessagesPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(groupBox);
```

You can also use the position of new GroupBox added :

```
MessagesPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(
             groupBox.Right - MessagesPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X,
             groupBox.Bottom - MessagesPanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
```

The best is using `flowLayoutPanel` instead of `Panel` :

Try to add `flowLayoutPanel`

1. Set `myFlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown`
2. If you don't want multiple rows or columns set the `WrapContents` property to `false`
3. SetAutoScroll property to true

Comment: Thanks. The first solution leads to a weird result: the scroll bar gets to about half of the panel, and there is a weird space added above all the `groupbox`es. Here is a demonstration: http://i.imgur.com/hJyJ2yy.gifv.
The second solution does just nothing... The scroll bar stays at the top, but no space is added: http://i.imgur.com/7y4IZsh.png?1. Thanks again,

Comment: I am sorry but the answer doesn't help me... Please see my previous comment with the problems in the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have edit my answer for you ,test the flowLayoutPanel it should work.Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found @Gess 's answer better for my uses. Thanks again,